# T4 include in extension throws UriFormatException

Tags: visual-studio-2015, t4, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I am working on a VISIX project that would generate some classes with T4 templates. All my T4 templates include a common utility template 'Utilities.t4'. However when I initiate the generation of the code, I get the following error in VS 2015:

```
There was an error loading the include file 'Utilities.t4'. The transformation will not be run. The following Exception was thrown:

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
    at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) 
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.CheckSecurityZone(String path)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.TextTemplatingService.LoadIncludeText(String requestFileName, String& content, String& location)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Engine.ProcessIncludeDirective(Directive directive, ITextTemplatingEngineHost host, VisitedFiles includedFiles)

ClassMetadata.tt    13
```

The properties of the include file in VS are:

- Build Action - Content
- Copy to Output Directory - Copy if newer
- Custom Tool - (blank)
- Format Output - False
- Include in VISIX - true
- Transform on Build - false

Can someone please help with the problem?

Comment: what's in ClassMetadata.tt line 13?

Comment: This is the main template that includes the T4 include file utilities.t4.